# Webpack doesn't serve public files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've create a react app through the create-react-app package and I want to get a Add To Homescreen button on my app. I run my development server from `yarn start` on `localhost:8080`. I've added the `Bypass user engagement checks` in Chrome through > chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks

I navigate to my app in my browser (on the pc) and go into responsive manipulation, but I see a error in the log:

> Site cannot be installed: Page has no manifest  URL

The create-react-app plugin puts the Manifest in the `./public` folder but I'm using `webpack-dev-server` to start the app `"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot --env.presets serviceworker",`

In my webpack.config.js I have:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: '/public'
  },
```

My ./public folder contains the `manifest.json` file. But when I start the app I get the error:

> Site cannot be installed: Page has no manifest  URL

I think my webpack is not pointing to the correct folder, or the webpack config is wrong some other way.

Answer (score 0):

The path in the `contentBase` should start with a `.`. So:

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: './public'
},
```

And in my `src/index.html`:

```
<link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest" />
```

Now the `manifest` is loaded.